# C# percentage is 0

Tags: c#

I have a problem when I try to solve simple equation. My equation is find the percentage of student marks.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace thered_Try
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        decimal res;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int oneee = 300;
            int two = 1000;
            int thee = 10;
            res = (oneee / two) * 10;
            label1.Text = res.ToString();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is 0. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal oneee = 300;
            decimal two = 1000;
            decimal thee = 10;
            decimal aResult = (oneee / two) * 10;
            label1.Text = aResult.ToString("0.00");
        }
```

Comment: Mr.Dejo your code giving me error 

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) F:\vb.net\thered\thered Try\thered Try\Form1.cs 29 19 thered Try

Answer (score 2):

You're performing division between two integers - which means the result is computed as an integer too. 300 / 1000 is 0... and then you multiply that by 10, which is still 0.

Options:

- Use floating point arithmetic. You could do this by making all the variables `double`, or by casting:

  ret = (int) ((oneee / (double) two) * 10);

  (Other floating point types would work too, such as `decimal` or `float`... They may give very slightly different results in some cases.)
- Multiply by 10 *first*:

  ```
  res = (oneee * 10) / two;
  ```

Note that for a percentage, you'd want to multiply by 100, not 10. Multiplying first is probably simpler than using floating point *if* you only want an integer result, and *if* you know that the multiplication will never overflow.

Also note that to experiment with things like this quickly, it's much simpler to use a console app than Windows Forms. Here's a *complete* example showing it working:

```
using System;
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int oneee = 300;
        int two = 1000;
        int res = (oneee * 10) / two;
        Console.WriteLine(res); // 3        
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you were intending to use the [`p` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString), you should be using a floating point number instead:

```
int marksScored = 300;
int marksAvailable = 1000;
double proportion = ((double) marksScored) / marksAvailable;
string text = proportion.ToString("p1"); // "30.0%"
```

Note that only one operand of the division operator needs to be a `double` - although you could cast *both* of them if you find that clearer.

Comment: @user1927867: What do you mean? If you need to use the `p` format specifier, then your input should be a floating point number rather than an integer - and why are you multiplying by 10? (This is a good example of how it's hard to answer a question when the requirements aren't clear.)

Answer (score 0):

In all `C` based programming languages (like `C#`) the operation will be evaluated based on the highest type used in the expression. So if you will multiply two `integers` the compiler will use `integer` multiplication, but if you multiply a `float` and an `integer` the compiler will use `float` multiplication. In your case you divide two `integer`s so the compiler will use `integer` division.

To solve your problem you should transform one of the numbers into a `float`. You can do this in many ways. Here are a few:

```
res = ((float) oneee / two) * 10;
res = ((double) oneee / two) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are working with integers so the result is also integer and 0.3 becomes 0. You should use double instead or cast to double before calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The type of a result depends on the variables that are used.

Any mathematical operation between 2 `int`s will return an `int`.
You need to cast one of them to a decimal before doing the mathematical operation:

```
 res = (oneee / (decimal)two) * 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for all but i try this 


int oneee = 450;
            int two = 1000;
            int res = (oneee * 100) / two;
            MessageBox.Show(res.ToString("p1"));


resulte is 400.0%

the resulte must be 45%

Answer (score 0):

```
you are using int and when you are dividing it by 

(1000/300) it will result 0.3. But the data type is int, so result is 0;

Please use below code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace thered_Try
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        decimal res =0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal oneee = 300;
            decimal two = 1000;
            decimal thee = 10;
            res = (oneee / two) * 10;
            label1.Text = res.ToString();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

Thanks, Let me know your result.
```